# If I don't close Web Service connections, will this release the connection?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

If I create a Web Service, for example an ASMX or WCF Service, on the server and connect to it via a client.

Will the Connection close (be returned to the pool) if I do not explicitly tell the client to close the connection or will it remain open even after the client is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection will be closed automatically according to the default timeout value or what you have stated in your web.config file.

The default value is **1 minute**.

```
<configuration>  
   <system.serviceModel>  
      <bindings>  
         <wsHttpBinding>  
            <binding openTimeout="00:10:00"   
                     closeTimeout="00:10:00"   
                     sendTimeout="00:10:00"   
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00">  
            </binding>  
         </wsHttpBinding>  
      </bindings>  
  </system.serviceModel>
```